# Lightbox и ошибки валидатора

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lightbox

Стоит плагин WP Lightbox 2 для WordPress, и получается, что валидатор ругается на `rel="lightbox[2]"` (плагин добавляет).

```
<a href="/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/7.jpg" rel="lightbox[2]">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-105 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/7-300x225.jpg" alt="7" width="300" height="225">
</a>
```

Типа что их много, а значения `(rel="")` должны быть разными.

Может, кто-нибудь знает другой плагин, альтернативу/способ решения проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Забейте, валидатор не истинна в последней инстанции, и применять его надо с умом, эта ошибка - мелочь. Или меняйте плагин на тот, у которого атрибут для активации содержит data-.